# canDisplayBannerAds causes functionality not to work?

Tags: ios, swift, iad

So I have an app that on buttonPressed() the apps background view color changes.  All worked fine until I added iAds to monetize.

Essentially, calling:

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

causes the background color to stop changing. When I comment it out it works, and I could just probably comment it out and move on.  But I want to understand why it is causing it stop certain functionality.  Thanks!

Function to change button color:

```
view.backgroundColor = getRandomColor()

func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{

    var randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    var randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    var randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

    return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that changes your view's background color.

Comment: Just updated the question with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
originalContentView.backgroundColor = getRandomColor
```